# How can assign multiple html element values in one call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of radio buttons with several duplicate attributes. Can I somehow assign all these in one place, maybe like `[a, b, c] = (js)()`? Thank you.

```
<input type="radio" value={`${index}-0`} 
                      key={`${index}-0`} 
                       id={`${index}-0`}
  checked={this.state.selections[index] === 0 }
  onChange={this.handleChange} />
<label htmlFor={`${index}-0`} className="pure-radio"> 0 </label>
```

Comment: Did you try to map all of them to the same model(variable)?

Comment: If you were using [Angular](https://angular.io/), you can simply write `<input type="radio" [value]="index0" [key]="index0" [id]="index0">` in your template file and change `index0` in your js file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just assign them to the same variable? It's not quite what you are wanting, but better than your current situation.

```
var key = `${index}-0`;
...
<input type="radio" value={key} 
                  key={key} 
                   id={key}
                 checked={this.state.selections[index] === 0 }
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
<label htmlFor={key} className="pure-radio"> 0 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the attributes of an element is saved in [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

```
const attrs = document.getElementById('your_id').attributes
```

You can loop through them to access the attributes. See the example in the provided link.

Or, you can use [getNamedItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap/getNamedItem) to access desired attribute:

```
attrs.getNamedItem('id') // to get id attribute
```